# github fork management - branches

Tags: github

I made my fork from outsourcing project. Then I made a mistake - I commit some changes to it. Now I would like to make a branch with this changes, but I would like to have master all the time the same as original project I forked from. I created branch from master, so I already have my changes in branch. But how can I revert master now? Or fork it again from original project? How can I make it updated? And finally - how should I commit changes next time (each commit I would like to have in separate branch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset master:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

(with '`upstream`' being the name of the remote referencing the url of the original repo that you have forked)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't get last line. While trying to do that I get: git reset --hard upstream/origin
fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: @Malvinka what does `git remote -v` returns? do you see `upstream` in the output?

Comment: yes. It looks like that: origin my/github/repo/url  (fetch)
origin my/github/repo/url (push)
upstream project/github/url (fetch)
upstream project/github/url (push)

Comment: And after the `git fetch upstream` step, do you see `upstream/master` in the output of `git branch -avv`?

Comment: ok. I get it. Stupid mistake. I do not know why, but I was trying to do upstream/origin o.O Sorry, and thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry, but still I do not have what I need. I did everything what you said, but I'm afraid I am not sure what I've done... I reset master on my local repo, am I right? I should now do git push to have the same on master on github (that didn't change there). If I was trying to do that I have a failed msg and hint about git pull - it makes me to marge, which I do not want to do...

Comment: @Malvinka yes, you would still need to do a `git push --force origin master`, in order to reset master on GitHub to the same SHA1.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks a lot (especially for your patience ;) )